# Incorrect syntax around datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

The following CREATE statement is meant for SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE tclientlink 
(
     link_id INT,
     ext_client_id VARCHAR(255),
     goald_address_id VARCHAR(255),
     goald_client_id VARCHAR(255),
     instance_id VARCHAR(255),
     source_id VARCHAR(255),
     timestamp DATETIME2
);
```

The `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO TCLIENTLINK(link_id, ext_client_id, goald_address_id, goald_client_id, instance_id, source_id, timestamp) 
VALUES (13582, "0000059811", "3037260", "0000059811", "1", "1", 2018-08-22 15:13:34);
```

But when I try to validate this using an online tool, I get the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'datetime2 )'

What change do I need to make to my DDL above?

Comment: This works in SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b8308.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, that's the tool I used. But I tried again just now, and I get this error: _You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'datetime2 )' at line 8_

Comment: 'timestamp' is a reserved SQL word and datatype in SQL Server. Try either using a different name, or enclosing it in square brackets, like [timestamp], and see if that works for you.

Comment: I found the problem. On SQL Fiddle, it was expecting MySQL rather SQL Server. I changed to SQL Server and the CREATE now works. But the following INSERT is now not working: _INSERT INTO TCLIENTLINK(link_id, ext_client_id, goald_address_id, goald_client_id, instance_id, source_id, timestamp)
VALUES(13582, "0000059811", "3037260", "0000059811", "1", "1", 2018-08-22 15:13:34);_. I think it's an issue around the timestamp entry

Comment: You need to put the literal string representing the date into single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double quote indicate column name, as a result if you use double quote sql server engine will search that column name , so in case of value you have to use single quote and also for datetime column value should be quoted. so working query is below

```
CREATE TABLE tclientlink 
(
     link_id INT,
     ext_client_id VARCHAR(255),
     goald_address_id VARCHAR(255),
     goald_client_id VARCHAR(255),
     instance_id VARCHAR(255),
     source_id VARCHAR(255),
     timestamp DATETIME2
);

INSERT INTO TCLIENTLINK(link_id, ext_client_id, goald_address_id, goald_client_id, instance_id, source_id, timestamp) 
VALUES (13582, '0000059811', '3037260', '0000059811', '1', '1', '2018-08-22 15:13:34');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement might be this.

use `'` instead of `"` for string value, and the datetime2 need to use `'` contain it.

```
INSERT INTO TCLIENTLINK(link_id, ext_client_id, goald_address_id, goald_client_id, instance_id, source_id, timestamp) VALUES(13582,'0000059811','3037260','0000059811','1','1', '2018-08-22 15:13:34');
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=52ec43bdeab5276b78d86c4f94209ba7)